# Asp.NET Delegation and Calling a SharePoint Webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I'm trying to make a call to the SharePoint Search Webservice from an Asp.NET 4.0 application that does not reside on the SharePoint server. Everything seems to work, accept it is using the AppPool's credentials (a domain service account) to authenticate to SharePoint, which only returns results that that pin has access to. What I need to be able to do is impersonate the calling user, so that I get results for that user and not the domain account. I've set the server that the application is running under up to be trusted for delegation to the http spn that the SharePoint server is using, but I get a 401 error when doing the impersonation in my code. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I'd try posting this on http://serverfault.com/ :-)

Comment: Turns out the delegation wasn't set up properly. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

you have to impersonate your call to the sharepoint web service.

you can do this at a web application level, with either the calling user or a static user, inside the web.config in the system.web node using the identity element, i.e...

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

or you can do this with inline code when you make your requesting call.

here is a microsoft KB on how to impersonate with an asp.net application. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is finally working right...the AD guys didn't set up the delegation properly, so now that that is fixed the impersonation is working properly. Thanks again!